# How to create new excel spreadsheet by subtracting duplicates of another spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel spread sheets.
Test1 Test2.
Test1 has user1, user2, user3, and so on.
Test2 had user1, user2, and user5.
I would like to remove user1, user2, and user5 from Test1.

This is an example. Long story short. I have two excel spreadsheets that pull data. One is autogenerated the other is one I made. I would like to remove the users from the made spreadsheet and create a new spreadsheet that displays only the users from Test1 after removing users listed on Test2.

I am using python and pandas and have found no solutions to this.

So far I have tried doing research on python and pandas. My original solution was to manually remove the users every week to create a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly?

```
import pandas as pd


path = "/path/to/files/"
test1 = pd.read_excel(f"{path}Test1.xlsx")
users2 = pd.read_excel(f"{path}Test2.xlsx").users.unique()

users1 = test1.users.unique()
user_intersection = set(users1).intersection(users2)

test1.query("~users.isin(@user_intersection)").reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(f"{path}/Test3.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to work for me. Whenever I put in users2 = pd.read_excel(f"{path}Test2.xlsx").users.unique(). I get errors.

Comment: what kind of error? Do you need to specify a sheet? Is your path wrong?